# Should we be able to embed Youtube videos?

Tags: feature-request, video

I am suggesting that users of User Experience on StackExchange are allowed to use embedded video in questions and answers. User Experience is often a process of completing tasks, which sometimes is hard to explain in text and images. An embedded video could improve both askers and answerers to better explain their true meaning. An example of this would be the question [If input text length is known, do I really need a submit button?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18499/if-input-text-length-is-known-do-i-really-need-a-submit-button) where [embedding this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzUMOrQ4wO0), would improve the question and explain to askers the task completion process.

Sometimes users ask for definition of something, like the question [What's the definition of Information Architecture?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6652/whats-the-definition-of-information-architecture) One way to answer that question could be to embed videos that explain both [information](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WytNkw1xOIc) and [architecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E55OcGB0L8o), separately.

However, the textual content should still be the core of a questions and answers and videos should only be used to improve content. I’m not suggesting that video content should replace textual content.

Other Examples:

[Is it better to have an icon in front of validation messages?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/21441/7627)

---

<sup>*Notes to reader:*</sup>

<sup>*If you approve of this feature request, and have other examples where embedded video could improve content; feel free to edit this post.*</sup>

<sup>Discussion on the subject: [Why don't we allow embedded video in questions and answers?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/936/why-dont-we-allow-embedded-video-in-questions-and-answers)</sup>

Comment: I went and made this CW so people can add examples and made the title more clear (youtube embedding is the only form of videos the other sites get)

Comment: @BenBrocka Thanx! This improves the probability of a success!